# Can't compile a project: Getter created by lombok doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, lombok

I have a spring boot project building by gradle. When I compiled that, it failed because of a lombok problem.

```
error: cannot find symbol
        sampleClass.getId();
                   ^
```

I think it's weird because it looks like there is no problem on the editor screen.
[image]
A Data class is:

```java
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class SampleClass {
    private int id;
}
```

And a Controller class is:

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getTop()
    {
        SampleClass sampleClass = new SampleClass();
        sampleClass.getId();
        return "test";
    }

}
```

dependencies on build.gradle is:

```java
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.10'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain this problem?
thanks.

Comment: did u set Annotation Processors properly ? Settings -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors

Comment: maybe you also require the lombok plugin in your ide.

Comment: In my case, annotation processing is enabled. thokuest's answer worked for me very well. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing to define the Lombok dependency in the `annotationProcessor` configuration.

```
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

Since you're using Spring Boot, you can remove the `version` from that particular dependency as it's already defined by the *Spring Dependency Management* plugin.

For full context, have a look at the respective project created by [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.1.11.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=1.8&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=lombok).

Comment: It worked! the issue completely seems to be solved. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ShintaroNomiya so accept @thokuest answer. Also you might've want to delegate build to Gradle to avoid similar situations with other tooling. `Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Build and Run using --- Gradle`

Answer (score 3):

1. Check if *Annotation Processing* is enabled:

> File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors

2. Check if Lombok plugin is installed (restart IDE after plugin installation):

> File > Settings > Plugins

3. Try different Lombok version. (currently newest one is 1.18.10)
4. Make sure to include `annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'` in Gradle project settings.

From [this](https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle) Lombok setup page:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
}
```